# Access Website from Powerbuilder and upload/map file for file object control

Tags: internet-explorer, ole, powerbuilder

I am able to navigate the url, login and go to particular URL. Now i have struck at file upload level. Could anybody help me?

variable type is coming as 'file' , how to pass file path and name to this in PB. Below is my script

```
 IE = CREATE OLEObject
 IE.ConnectToNewObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

 IE.left=200
 IE.top=200
 IE.height=400
 IE.width=400
 IE.menubar=1
 IE.toolbar=1
 IE.statusBar=1
 IE.navigate("http://www.xyz.in/index.php")

 IE.visible=1
 SetForegroundWindow( IE.HWND )

 DO WHILE IE.Busy
  Yield ()
 LOOP

 li_form_ctr = IE.Document.Forms.Length
 if li_form_ctr = 1 then
   li_form_ctr = li_form_ctr - 1
   IE.Document.Forms[li_form_ctr].Elements.username.Value = 'Test'
   IE.Document.Forms[li_form_ctr].Elements.password.Value = 'test@123'
   ls_OldURL = IE.LocationURL
   IE.Document.Forms[li_form_ctr].Elements.submit.Click()
 else
  return
 end if   
DO WHILE IE.Busy
 Yield ()
LOOP
if ls_OldURL = IE.LocationURL then
   messagebox("Error","Either User Name/Password Wrong")
else
  IE.navigate("http://www.xyz.in/upload_ecr_latest.php")
  DO WHILE IE.Busy
    Yield ()
  LOOP
  sleep(2)
  li_form_ctr = 0
  li_form_ctr = IE.Document.Forms.Length
  if li_form_ctr = 1 then
     li_form_ctr = li_form_ctr - 1
     IE.Document.Forms[li_form_ctr].Elements.month.Value = '08'
     IE.Document.Forms[li_form_ctr].Elements.year.Value = '2014'
     IE.Document.Forms[li_form_ctr].Elements.ecr = "D:\temp\xyz.txt"  -- This one is Not working
     ls_OldURL = IE.LocationURL
     IE.Document.Forms[li_form_ctr].Elements.upload.Click()
   else
      return
  end if       
end if
```

Narayana

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are doing a synchronous type communication with the control, which apparently works for the situation but I don't know if it will work good for a file upload or not.

I think what you need to do is inherit from "inet" object, and "internetresult" to create your own descendants where you can grab results using the navigatecomplete, etc., events which will have arguments that you can use containing the actual payload data.

Let me know if you need clarifications but if you research inet, internetobject I think you will figure it out. It is possible the events you need are available on your OLE object but I don't know for sure, have never done it that way.

Comment: I have tried inet also but no luck, but if you have a sample code you can provide me. I have tried winhttp method also but no luck